# Application fails to load on first run. (Cannot convert undefined or null to object)

Tags: redux, react-redux, persist, redux-offline

Everything was working fine before I added redux-offline in my store.

```
export const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(middleware, offline(offlineConfig))
);
```

This is an error when I load the application for the first time. If I refresh again the error goes away.

[image]

Comment: Can you give more code? What is the value of offlineConfig?

Comment: @DanielStoyanoff import offlineConfig from '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/defaults';